# Nodejs - Response of POST request is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, http-post

I'm learning nodejs, and made a simple site to learn to handle POST requests.

Here is my code:

Browser-side:

```
function sendRequest (params) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'result';
  xhr.open("POST",url,true);

  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log('onreadystatechange');
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
      console.log('Response text:' + xhr.reponseText);
    }
  }

  xhr.send(params);
}
```

Server-side:

```
else if (req.url === '/result') {
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        var params = data.toString().split('&');
        var result = calc(params);
        console.log(result.toString());
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
        res.write('<div>'+result.toString()+'</div>');
        res.end();
        console.log('Response over');
    });
  }
```

When i run this,`xhr.responseText` is `undefined`, and i'm having trouble understanding where the error is.

Based on the log, node gets the request, the result is correct,and `xhr.onreadystatechange` also runs(but `xhr.responseText` is undefined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is typing error in your browser side code. You misspelled `responseText`.

```
console.log('Response text:' + xhr.responseText);
```

Comment: Wow...That was embarrassing

Comment: Took me a while to figure out too as well :)